# when debuging python file in vscode, launch program seems to run the full file before pause in the first breakpoint

Tags: python, vscode-debugger

[image]
print line is behine the first breakpoint, but the result is already in terminal

I tryed to look https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging but not find any similar args.

**edit:**

I realize that the problem will only occur when I name the file django.py.

When I rename the file to other name like website.py, it won't occur.

I wander if there are other names that will trigger this bug.

below are my launch.json

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: 当前文件",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `django.py` conflicts with other files.

An extract from the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/intro/tutorial01/#:%7E:text=running%20django%2Dadmin.-,Note,-You%E2%80%99ll%20need%20to)

> You’ll need to avoid naming projects after built-in Python or Django components. In particular, this means you should avoid using names like `django` (which will conflict with Django itself) or test (which conflicts with a built-in Python package).

---

I.e. some other process(es) is looking for, and running `django.py`. And your file is over-writing the other file.

To fix your issue, just avoid naming the file `django.py` or `test.py`

Comment: I find that if I use django.py as the file name, it will run the whole file before my breakpoint.
But if I choose other word as filename, the problem will not happen, even if I don't write a main function.

Comment: Interesting, do you have any other files in your directory?

Comment: Sorry, i just remembered the naming conventions, see updated answer @k-on_mio